# get_adjacent_post - in same term or category not working

Tags: navigation, single, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am building a Next and Previous Post navigation for my 'Single post' pages, inside a plugin. What I am trying to do is get the Prev/Next post within the same category of a Custom Post Type.

So I have a CPT of **'Movies'** with a taxonomy of **'Genre'** with terms **'Drama, Thriller'**, Thriller is a child of the Drama term. I have multiple posts that have the categories 'Drama->Thriller'. If I am viewing one of these posts I would like to stay within the 'Thriller' category as I navigate through Prev/Next.

My code below attempts to achieve this but what I end up with for **'get_adjacent_post()' are empty strings**.

Code breakdown:

1. Hook into the 'wp_link_pages' filter to update navigation logic
2. Find the $post current taxonomy
3. Initially add all 'term_id' to $exclude_ids
4. Find the first term that has a parent term
5. Setup current taxonomy
6. Remove $chosen term from $excluded_ids
7. break out of the loop

I have hardcoded the $excluded_ids with '9' (9 = Drama) for now because I know this is the term id I need to exclude allowing only for 'Thriller' term id to be used to find Prev/Next posts.

I am open to any suggestions, either fixing this code or coming up with someone completely different to achieve this.

Appreciate your time
,

```
add_filter('wp_link_pages', array( $this, 'replace_paginated_posts'), 10, 2);

public function replace_paginated_posts( $output, $args ) {

global $wp_query, $post, $page, $numpages;

// Get all taxonomies for current post
$chosen = 0;
$tax = '';
$excluded_ids;
$taxonomies = get_the_taxonomies($post);
foreach ($taxonomies as $key => $value) {
    // Get post terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $key );

    // Get all the term id's
    $excluded_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms , 'term_id' );
    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
        // get the first term that has a parent and select its term
        if ($term->parent > 0) {
            $chosen = $term->term_id;
            $tax = $term->taxonomy;
        }
        if ($chosen != 0) {
            // Remove $chosen term from $excluded_ids;
            $excluded_ids = array_diff($excluded_ids, array($chosen) );
            break;
        }
    }
}

if ($chosen == 0) {
    $excluded_ids = '';
}

$prev_post_link = get_permalink( get_adjacent_post(true, '9', true, $tax) );
$next_post_link = get_permalink( get_adjacent_post(true, '9', false, $tax) );

ob_start();
echo '<nav class="post-navigation">';

echo '<a href="'.$prev_post_link.'">Previous Post</a>';
echo '<a href="'.$next_post_link.'">Next Post</a>';

echo '</nav>';

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $output;
}
```

**EDIT:** I am receiving a SQL error

```
WordPress database error: []
SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE p.post_date > '2016-04-04 23:21:34' AND p.post_type = 'movies' AND tt.taxonomy = 'genre' AND tt.term_id IN (12,13,14,10) AND p.ID NOT IN ( SELECT tr.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE tt.term_id IN (9) ) AND ( p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'private' ) ORDER BY p.post_date ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It looks like there are many reasons why `get_adjacent_post()` may spit back an empty string. A couple troubleshooting questions: 1) if you add the `$wpdb` global variable to your function and a call to `$wpdb->print_error();` after `get_adjacent_post()`, are any errors printed? 2) have you verified that `$tax` is `'genre'` (or equivalent) in your calls to `get_adjacent_post()`? 3) You mentioned some movies have the terms "Drama->Thriller" - is that to say they are attributed with "Thriller" or both "Drama" and "Thriller"?

Comment: I edited my answer to show the SQL error I am receiving. Yes, I am getting the correct taxonomy of 'genre' and chosen of '10' in my loop. But I am still receive this SQL error even when I hard code the args into the function '$prev = get_adjacent_post(true, '9', true, 'genre');'

Comment: what is the code you use for post navigation in theme?

Comment: The plugin works by updating your theme anywhere you are using the template tag 'wp_link_pages', that is why the entry to my plugin logic starts with the 'wp_link_pages' filter hook.

Comment: if your plugin works later, what is the different with WordPress function [`the_post_navigation`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation/)

Comment: [`wp_link_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) build for paged of your content, others content paged will break by your plugin.

Comment: Thank Jevuska. My plugin also handles paginated posts, but there is an option to swap out paginated post links (<--1,2,3,4,5, -->) for a button that says 'Next Page' until you come to the last page of the pagination and then it says 'Next Post'. Also, I am trying to make this backwards compatible before WP 4.1 so trying to stay away from using 'post_navigation'.  Is there a better hook you would recommend to use?

Comment: @George If I'm reading that MySQL query in the error correctly, it would seem that the `$excluded_terms` argument of `get_adjacent_post()` deliberately excludes all posts containing any excluded term, even if `$in_same_term` is `true` and those posts share a non-excluded term in the appropriate taxonomy. Does `get_adjacent_post()` return something/the database error disappear when you omit the `'9'` argument?

Comment: Yes, when I set it to empty string " ", I receive a different SQL error, SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE p.menu_order > '5' AND p.post_type = 'movies' AND tt.taxonomy = 'genre' AND tt.term_id IN (9,10) AND ( p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'private' ) ORDER BY p.menu_order ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Like I mentioned I am open to a completely different way of approaching the problem. Not sure how, but is there a SQL query that can be written that will achieve this same functionality without using get_adjacent_post()

Comment: I think the most "WordPress-y" way to implement this short of creating your own template functions would be to modify the `get_next_post()` and `get_previous_post()` template tags rather than `wp_link_pages()` - which means modifying the `get_adjacent_post()` query to constrain "adjacency" to the "current" or "chosen" term. You *could* keep it simple and just use a custom `WP_Query` instead of relying on `get_adjacent_post()` at all - it would be the quickest solution, if hacky. I'm going to play with modifying the `get_adjacent_post()` query when I have a little time.

Comment: Thanks, Bosco, I came to the same conclusion too, I ended up using WP_Query and everything is working great. I have never understood why in the 'wp_posts' table they didn't decide to add a post's taxonomy and terms, I can think of all kinds of situations where that would be helpful.

Comment: If you figure out how to modify the get_adjacent_post() query I would be very interested in your solution. Take it easy.